# PHP - Populating HTML <select>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm probably overlooking something, but this is the code I have written that will print the contents of a HTML select tag.

```
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
        <select name="List" id="List">
            <?php PopulateBox(); ?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

And then in my PHP file:

```
function PopulateBox()
{

    //MySQL connection stuff up here

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ItemNo FROM Items");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['ItemNo'] . ">" . $row['ItemNo'] . "</option>";       
    }
}
```

There are currently 10 items in this table, but the output only generates 5 items in the HTML select box.

Why is this happening?

Edit: I see this when I do print_r:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 10
    [type] => 0
)
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML?

Comment: Your HTML looks malformed, your `<option>` tags `value` attribute doesn't have its quotes closed. You open them, but don't close them afterwards.

Comment: You should decouple your code and DRY. That function can not be reused. But as stated by @Alex.Ritna your quotes are open. I recommend using single quotes `echo '<option value="' . $some_value . '"'`...

Comment: Don't see why it is closed because "a problem that cannot be reproduced" considering someone was able to spot my error.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['ItemNo'] . ">" . $row['ItemNo'] . "</option>";
```

From looking at this line, there's an end quotation mark missing in the HTML output. Perhaps this would work:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['ItemNo'] . "\">" . $row['ItemNo'] . "</option>";
```